# Create a column comment in python source file

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, comments, edit

Hello I want to create a comment section right next to all my code lines for documentation purposes. I have over 1000 lines of code and I don't want to place all the `#` by myself.

The result I want to achieve:

```py
    code()              # comment
    code()              # comment
    code()              # comment
    code()              # comment
```

Is there a way to do this automaticly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of extensions that do this well. See, e.g., [Simple Alignment](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=earshinov.simple-alignment).  Just select the characters you want to align.

[image: betterAlign]

You can bind the `Align` command to a keybinding if you want.

```
{
  "key": "alt+a",
  "command": "simple-alignment.align"
},
```

Comment: Thank you for you solution. Will look into it!

Answer (score 1):

you can place Multi Cursors.

Make sure you don't have `Word Wrap` enabled

1. click on the first line
2. Shift+Alt Click on the last line
3. End - to go to the end of the line
4. Type a number of spaces to make all lines larger than your comment column
5. Home - go to start of line
6. Use Arrow Right to move to your comment column
7. Sift+End Delete - to remove extra spaces
8. Type `# comment`
9. Esc - to leave Multi Cursor